# VBA: Excel script going into another sub without reason, Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

So I am creating a form on excel using activeX and form controls. The form (for the most part) works exactly as intended. That is except for a strange interaction that is occurring between two separate activeX ComboBoxes. Both the ComboBoxes have subs attached to them that hide/unhide different rows. The issue that I am having is that when the second sub's lines are commented out the first sub runs correctly. But when neither are commented the first sub skips over parts of its own code and goes into the other sub and inevitably throws a Run time error 1004.

I have tried even moving the second sub into two separate subs withing another module to try and avoid the issue, however that didn't work correctly.

Both subs are right here ... The lines that cause are still left commented so anyone looking at this will know where the error occurs.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If ComboBox1 = "Field Failure" Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ComboBox1.AutoSize = False
    [16:18].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    [16:16].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

ElseIf ComboBox1 = "ACUTEC Customer" Then
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect
     [16:18].EntireRow.Hidden = True
     [17:18].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
         True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
Else
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  Rows("16:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox13_Change()
ComboBox13.AutoSize = False
If ComboBox13 = "No" Then
 Call Combo13Hide
ElseIf ComboBox13 = "Unknown" Then
 Call Combo13Hide
Else
 Call Combo13Unhide
End If
End Sub
```

In Other Module

```
Public Sub Combo13Hide()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  'Rows("21:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Range("J20").Value = ""
  ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub

Public Sub Combo13Unhide()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    'Rows("21:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("J20").Value = "Please comment on the repeat issue, including 
        related notification numbers or other applicable data"
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, and I would be happy to provide any additional information

Comment: any reason you're using ActiveX controls in favor of Form Controls?  Not sure what would cause this, but ActiveX are notoriously problematic IMO.

Comment: Works just for me. Did you try stepping through the code?

Comment: I just made some changes to my post. you may have to refresh it to see it

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but when I tried your above code, it didn't give me any error. I also see lot of unnecessary repetitions in your code. You entire code can be written as

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Rows("16:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    If ComboBox1 = "Field Failure" Then
        Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "ACUTEC Customer" Then
        Rows("17:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, _
    Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox13_Change()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    If ComboBox13 = "No" Or ComboBox13 = "Unknown" Then
        Range("J20").ClearContents
    Else
        Range("J20").Value = "Please comment on the repeat issue, " & _
        "including  related notification numbers or other applicable data"
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

**Note**: Try this code and see if you are still getting the error. You need to paste this code in the worksheet code area which has the combo boxes.

And if you are still getting the error then use this code and tell us what error message do you see?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

10    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

20    Rows("16:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True

30    If ComboBox1 = "Field Failure" Then
40        Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = False
50    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "ACUTEC Customer" Then
60        Rows("17:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
70    End If

80    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, _
      Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
LetsContinue:
90    Exit Sub
Whoa:
100    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl
110    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox13_Change()
    On Error GoTo WTF

10    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
20    If ComboBox13 = "No" Or ComboBox13 = "Unknown" Then
30        Range("J20").ClearContents
40    Else
50        Range("J20").Value = "Please comment on the repeat issue, " & _
        "including  related notification numbers or other applicable data"
60    End If
70    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, _
    Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
BRB:
80    Exit Sub
WTF:
90    MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl
100    Resume BRB
End Sub
```

Comment: I put in this code. When I tried to change ComboBoxes the first throws               "ClearContents method of Range class failed 30". The second box throws "We cant do that to a merged cell 30" when I select No or Unknown. I'm assuming that these may be referencing the same line in the ComboBox13 sub, which still doesn't answer the question as to how its possible for the code to skip into another sub in this way. I'm going to changing a few more things and I will post the results of what I find.

Comment: I made a simple change, since the numbering was ambiguous as to which sub was referenced in the message, so I simply changed the numbering in ComboBox13 to 11, 21, 31, ect ... As I had guessed both ComboBoxes threw a message with the number 31, so the ComboBox1 sub is still going into ComboBox13 somehow? Also I commented out the Clear and Value statements in ComboBox13 and that stopped the errors

Comment: you didnt have to change the numbering.. you could have added few words to the error handler. For example `MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl & " in Sub ComboBox1_Change()"` and `MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl & " in Sub ComboBox13_Change()"`

Answer (score 0):

So although it doesn't answer the core problem of my issue it seems that a few modifications on Siddharth Rout's was able to get my form to work as I needed.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
On Error GoTo Whoa

10    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

20    Rows("16:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True

30    If ComboBox1 = "Field Failure" Then
40        Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = False
50    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "ACUTEC Customer" Then
60        Rows("17:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
70    End If

80    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, _
       Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
  LetsContinue:
90    Exit Sub
Whoa:
100    'MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl
110    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox13_Change()
     On Error GoTo WTF

11    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
21    If ComboBox13 = "No" Or ComboBox13 = "Unknown" Then
          Rows(21).EntireRow.Hidden = True
          Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = True
41    Else
          Rows(21).EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Rows(22).EntireRow.Hidden = False
61    End If
71    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, _
       Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
BRB:
81    Exit Sub
WTF:
91    'MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & Erl
101   Resume BRB
End Sub
```

However, as I stated this still doesn't answer how the ComboBox1 sub was able to pass into the ComboBox13 sub.